# Can someone tell me please how to reconnect to my remote repository GitHub from git using personal access tokens?

Tags: git, github

A few hours ago i had no problems with my remote repository (GitHub) then a few hours later i got this warring  message on the commande line when tried to push my commits `remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead. remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information. fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Adems/Omi.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403` I actually generated my GitHub PAT and tried to reconnect to my remote repo using git clone  but it copies directly the repo and doesn't show anything to enter my PAT. Could someone help me out with this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a Personal Access Token for your account. [See here to create your PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)

Your PAT should start with `ghp_`

2. Open you `Keychain Access` app, search for `github` & delete your existing saved passwords
3. Go back to your terminal & try pushing your commit, it should prompt for your user name & password. Now, try entering your PAT in place of your usual GitHub password/passphrase.